# Regular Expression for the word in the Link

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to write a regular expression for **link.php?id=** that present in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actually on that page i.e. link.php then you can use `$_GET['id']` to get the ID param value.

If you need regex to match a string then you can use...

```
$str = "link.php?id=45";

if (preg_match("/link\.php\?id=(\d+)/", $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1]; // would give you the number 45
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is match it against the word and then escape the chars that are operational characters. (http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

I think ?[link.php\?id=] should do the trick.